# How to write trigger on self relationship object?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom object which is having a relationship with the same object. I need to update the first child record of the custom object record.

[image]

As shown above, the Broker object's record is having self-relationship and having 2 records.

I have to update the first created child record's IsFisrt__c field. I am not sure how to update the same record using a trigger.

Can anyone please help with trigger how to update self-relation object.

Comment: There's no particular uniqueness about a trigger on an object with a self-relationship, but you will have to be careful with your logic. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi David, I stuck at self-relation object query. How to get child records of own object?. I know how to write a trigger when there is lookup with other objects. we can query like List<Child_Object__c> l_co = [SELECT Id, Amount__c FROM Child_Object__c WHERE Parent_Lookup__c = :po.Id];  when there is a relationship with other objects. But how to query to get child records of the same same object record?

Answer (score 1):

Self-lookup relationships can be queried in exactly the same way as any other Salesforce relationship.

Given a custom object `My_Object__c` with a self-lookup field `Parent__c` that has the relationship name `Children`, you can query child-to-parent:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM My_Object__c WHERE Parent__c = :someParentRecordId
```

or parent-to-child:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Children__r) FROM My_Object__c
```